# Unable to find vmware Workstation driver while using docker-machine

Tags: docker-machine

I have installed Win 7 on my laptop then installed VMware Workstation 9 on which I am running linux destro "Centos-6_64-Bit".

I have stated learning docker & containers. So I have installed docker-machine and docker-engine on Centos-6_64-bit. I am not able to find VMware drivers on docker-machine. Below is the command and error i am getting :-

root@sourav_64 tmp]# docker-machine create --driver=vmwareworkstation default

**Driver "vmwareworkstation" not found. Do you have the plugin binary "docker-machine-driver-vmwareworkstation" accessible in your PATH?**

Regards,
Shourabh Singh

Answer (score 0):

`vmwareworkstation` is not an official driver included with Docker Machine. Of the VMWare products that include or manipulate hypervisors, VMWare Fusion is closest to what you're after. Here is the [documentation for that driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/vm-fusion/), as well as the [full list of drivers](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/) included in Docker Machine.

There are a couple of github repositories that offer what you're after. A search string of *docker driver workstation* will reveal them.